# Is it "Strategy" or "Template Method" pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I started to learn patterns recently, and i saw a lot of realizations of Strategy pattern like this, but my seniour friend said, that this is realization of "Template Method" pattern. Please help me identify the design pattern which applies to the code below:

```
interface IAnimal {
    void MakeSound();
}

class Dog : IAnimal {
    void MakeSound() {
        Console.WriteLine("hoof");
    }
}

class Cat : IAnimal {
    void MakeSound() {
        Console.WriteLine("meow");
    }
}

class Cow : IAnimal {
    void MakeSound() {
        Console.WriteLine("moo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's neither of the two patterns; in fact, it is not a pattern at all.

Strategy pattern would require a "context" class that relies on `IAnimal` for some other operation, while Template Method pattern would use some common implementation code that calls an overridable method from the subclass.

Your code illustrates the concept of inheritance, which is a common building block for the two patterns that you mentioned.